label is data or address?
I know it is a address, but why "move ax,var"(var is label at code section beginning),in MASM,it represent for"move ax,[0000]" and not "mov ax,0000",so label is address or data?Also, why run statement "c : dw a,b" and the data from c is 00 00 04 00,there label represents address,it really confused me.
assume cs: codeSeg
codeSeg segment
    a :db 12h,23h,34h,45h
    b :dw 67h,78h,89h,9ah
    c :dw a,b
start :
    mov ax , start + 1
    mov ax , a
    mov ax , b
    
    push a
    pop ax
    mov ax , [a]
    mov bx , [b]
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
codeSeg ends
end start


DOSBox isn't an assembler.  The code you posted looks like MASM or TASM syntax, not NASM, so yes, mov ax, var is implicitly the same as mov ax, [var], because MASM syntax is unfortunately designed that way, to try to hide details (which is the opposite of what you want when working with assembly, or especially learning it).  Confusing brackets in MASM32

but why run statement "c : dw a,b" and the data from c is 00 00 04 00,there label represents address,it really confused me.

In contexts other than operands for instructions, label names are addresses.  c: dw a,b doesn't "run" at run-time, it's only assembled to emit the absolute addresses.  (Or the offset part of them, actually).  You can't do dw [a], [b] to reference contents of memory you already emitted; if you wanted something like that you'd use an equ constant to avoid hard-coding the same number twice in the asm source.  How to reference the value of data section in macro? / Assemble-time read the value of a data variable

Oh,I fell more clear right now,I am really really appreciated for your help.It save my way learning assembly language.By the way, can you recommand some resources to learn assembly language or some authoritative documents to clarify the confusion like this?

@hahahaha: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for a lot of useful resources.

thank you so much,I am so glad to come across you here,I will try my best to be better,and I am really really appreciated for your help and recommandation.
